# Lego character hand doesn't move with the arm?

Tags: rigging, weight-painting

I am trying make my Lego character move the left arm in pose mode but when the arm moves part of the left hand stretches. I've been trying to fix the weight paint of the vertex group but have no luck.

[image]

[image: screenshot 1 rest pose]

[image: screenshot 2 deformed]
Update: Hi i fixed part of the hand but now the hand looks like this when the arm is moved.
[image: Screenshot 3 deformed still]

Comment: Hi. Please don't post essential information like links, file downloads or additional details in the comments section where it can be easily missed. Instead edit them into your original post with the [Edit] button above. Comments are transitory by nature, are hard to index or search for, and may be erased at any moment.

Comment: Hello, there's no link to your file here, just the jpg icon

Comment: the file link is fixed now.

Comment: thanks for fixing the link i kinda new so sorry for posting the link into the comments so i hope you find the problem and then tell me how to fix it

Comment: You're welcome. Your model has a few duplicated vertices. Select everything and remove them with key M > *Merge by Distance* in *Edit* mode. Then the hand and arm work with automatic weights. But manual weight painting might give you a better result. -- Lego figures don't have knees, do they? I think you don't that many bones for the legs.

Comment: By select everything do you mean just the hand or the whole model?

Comment: Okay your advice worked my model can move without the hand stretching thank you for helping me fix the model